# Are "the roof of the building" and "a house of stone" grammatically the same constructions?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, possessives

Are "the roof **of the building**" and "a house **of stone**" grammatically different prepositional phrase constructions? Or are they both understood to be possessives with the latter not in the usual sense of ownership/possession but something that "belongs" to a particular class or category?

Comment: They're both possessives. They have the same syntactic structure; both are noun phrases composed of an arthrous noun phrase modified by a prepositional phrase  with _of_. The _of_ phrase in _the building_ is arthrous, but the one in _a house_ has no article. The sense of the preposition is not part of syntax, but rather of semantics and pragmatics. Syntax is automatic and meaningless; meaning comes from use in context.

Comment: Prepositions are highly polysemous, but they _are_ also considered to be function words. Trivially, the first 'of' is 'belonging to' in the broader sense, and the second 'constructed from' (or arguably 'consisting of').

Comment: We can say "The building's roof" but not, of course, "the stone's house".  When we see something like "a book *of English*" could English in that phrase be analogous to "stone" in "house *of stone*"?

Comment: No: there is no grammatical difference. But note that they are not possessives. Of is not a genitive (possessive) case marker. The of PPs are simply **complements** (not modifiers) of the head nouns. Semantically, your first example indicates **a part of the whole**, while the second indicates **composition**.

Comment: [senses 3 and 4a here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)

Comment: Try the construction seen in "the roof of the house", but with two nouns joined by "and". "The roof of the house and the garage" fails because the two buildings have separate roofs. "The roofs of the house and the garage" is fine but denotes two separate possessions. By contrast, we may say "a house of stone and slate" or "a house of bricks and mortar" to say one house is composed of (at least) two materials.

Comment: @BillJ "part of the whole" is often conflated with possession, since we generally own our parts.

Comment: @BillJ: I read that **of** is a *functor* or *function word*.  Are there different categories of function? Would "house **of** stone" be said to attach or apply the attribute "stone" to the head noun, **house**, if "of stone" is not a "modifier"?

Comment: @Tim "Of" is a preposition.  Yes, the NP attributes a semantic relationship between the NP and the head noun, but the _of_ PP is a complement of the head noun, not a modifier. Even in genuine genitives such as "the teacher's car", the genitive NP "the teacher's" is a complement, not a modifier

Comment: @Barmar As I said earlier, I reject the claim that "of" is a genitive (possessive) marker. In any case, there is nothing in the OP's examples to suggest ownership.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of something like "that book of Barry's", but that actually has the possessive marker in "Barry's" in addition to "of". "the book of Barry" would not be possessive, it would be a section of the Bible. :)

Comment: Isn't the fact 'the roof of the building' and 'a house of stone' might both collapse due to context, with grammar incidental? Isn't the real Question about the possessives? ’The roof belonging to the building’ might share grammar with ’The house belonging to the stone’ but even without ‘the’, that would stretch the context out of normal recognition. ’The stone belonging to the house’ fits the grammar but strangles the context.